# how to wait for async function in foreach loop

Tags: node.js

I have some code like this, with `value.users.fetch()` return a promise:

```
console.log('1');

msg.reactions.cache.forEach(value => {
    value.users.fetch().then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })

});

console.log('3');
```

Output:

```
1
3
<some data here>
```

But i want it to be:

```
1
<some data here>
3
```

Is there anyway to wait for `value.users.fetch()` return inside forEach loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` method doesn't wait for the `async` operation to end before moving on to the next iteration.

You can use `async-await` syntax along with `for of` loop

```
async function foo() {
  console.log('1');

  for (const value of msg.reactions.cache) {
    const data = await value.users.fetch();
    console.log(data);
  }

  console.log('3');
}

foo();
```